# Underhanded contest (?): Anti-Virus wars

Tags: code-golf, underhanded

Prove anti-virus software is paranoid by making a program that simply opens and alphabetically sorts a CSV file, that will get flagged as a virus (or malware/spyware/any threat really) when run.

You will be assessed by the following criteria:

- Does the cross-platform anti-virus package ClamAV detect it as a threat?
- Your code is not actually a virus (if the code looks fishy it will be deducted points)
- Conciseness of code

The specific target for this challenge is the following version of ClamAV with the following virus definitions (current as of the posting of this challenge). Your program must trigger this set of software/definitions to be eligible.

You may wish to use a virtual machine for testing your code.

```
Latest ClamAV® stable release is: 0.98.1 
ClamAV Virus Databases:
main.cvd ver. 55 released on 17 Sep 2013 10:57 :0400 (sig count: 2424225)
daily.cvd ver. 18639 released on 19 Mar 2014 06:45 :0400 (sig count: 839186)
bytecode.cvd ver. 236 released on 05 Feb 2014 12:36 :0500 (sig count: 43)
safebrowsing.cvd ver. 41695 released on 19 Mar 2014 03:00 :0400 (sig count: 1147457)
```

Comment: Try answering a few questions first to gain a few rep, then post your questions as an answer in the [sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1211/proposed-questions-sandbox-mark-x?cb=1).

Comment: Hi Andy! Given the large number of different platforms and AV software out there, it's difficult to use "Does an anti-virus detect it as a threat" as an objective winning criterion. It would help to limit the target to a specific AV package with specific virus definitions. I've edited your post to use a specific free, cross-platform package. However, even with that clarification, it will help to decide clearly on what you want the winning condition for your question to be and tag it accordingly. Generally, popularity contests encourage creativity while code golf encourages conciseness.

Comment: "if the code looks fishy it will be deducted points" The whole purpose of this challenge is to write code that looks fishy.

Comment: @JonathanVanMatre I think even with this clarification it doesn't make a good popularity contest. The challenge basically says: *write some code which sorts csv* (whatever that means) *and then hide a malware signature inside this code*. That is not very specific and interesting in the main task, namely inserting the signature.

Comment: @Howard Even so, I am doing my best to [practice what I preach](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1292/are-we-too-shy-about-editing-questions-to-make-them-better).

Comment: @JonathanVanMatre It wasn't meant as criticism from my side but merely as a comment. In its current form it is imho no fit for a popularity contest. Currently I don't have an idea how to turn around this challenge and make it suitable. If this question was posted in the sandbox instead maybe someone would have posted an idea how to make it an ok question.

Comment: I suggest retagging as code-golf. Shortest code to alphasort a .csv file, trigger ClamAV version <x>, and NOT cause any actual harm wins. This would allow for interesting solutions that mix the signature with the sorting algorithm just so save on bytes.

Comment: Tag description on [tag:underhanded] says "...does one thing, but, in reality, does something else" - I don't think this meets the criteria of the tag

Comment: @professorfish I feel as though it may be a bit late to change parts of the question, considering it has already been answered

Comment: @AndyRama I'm not asking for the question to be changed, I'm just suggesting that the tags be changed

Comment: @professorfish I still beleive it meets those criteria. The program looks like a virus but is not one.

Comment: I'm closing this question because, [by community consensus](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8326/20469), underhanded challenges are no longer welcome on the site.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## bash (113)

```
sort -t, "$1"
#PK^C^D^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@D^@^@^@D^@^@^@^@^@^@^@X5O!P%@AP[4\PZX54(P^)7CC)7}$EICAR-STANDARD-ANTIVIRUS-TEST-FILE!$H+H*
```

The above uses [caret notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret_notation). Notably, `^@` indicates a null byte.

#### How it works

- `sort -t, "$1"` sorts the file specified as the first command-line argument (`$1`), using the comma character as field delimiter (`-t,`).
- `#` at the beginning of the second line comments it out; it will get ignored by bash.
- `PK^C^D^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@D^@^@^@D^@^@^@^@^@^@^@` is the shortest possible [*ZIP file local file header*](https://www.pkware.com/documents/APPNOTE/APPNOTE-1.0.txt):

  - `PK^C^D` (0x04034B50) is the *local file header signature*.
  - `^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@` specifies the ZIP version, a bit flag, the compression method and the compressed file's mtime and checksum. All are set to zero.
  - The twice occurring `D^@^@^@` (0x00000044 or 68) specifies the file's compressed and uncompressed length (68 bytes).
  - `^@^@^@^@` specifies the filename and extra header length. Both are set to zero.
- `X5O!P%@AP[4\PZX54(P^)7CC)7}$EICAR-STANDARD-ANTIVIRUS-TEST-FILE!$H+H*` is the 68 byte long  [EICAR test string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EICAR_test_file), which serves as the data associated to the above header.

This takes advantage of the fact that ClamAV will act on all *ZIP file local file headers*, even if they're encountered outside of actual ZIP files.

#### Malware scan

[VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/71fcbebf3679bb5c0f61896e0042ae1f9400ad2a0c66eb0d32ef5643e6aa8015/analysis/1395329382/) gives 15 false positives out of its current 51 scanners. This includes ClamAV.

Comment: Nice! If no one one-ups you by Monday night (PST) then you'll be the accepted answer :)

Comment: Not a 'false positive'

Comment: @JopVernooij: I'd say it is. ClamAV wouldn't act on the EICAR test string if it wasn't because of the *ZIP file local file header*. However, that header is malformed and there's no *end of central directory record*, so the data associated to the file header will never get extracted. The fact that I used a test signature instead of actual malicious code doesn't affect the result.